# Bind named DNS error EOL

Tags: dns, centos

I am getting the following error, been trying t track it down with no luck. Any ideas?

```
        Error in named configuration:
        dns_rdata_fromtext: acme8.lcl.zone:2: near eol: unexpected end of input
        acme8.lcl.zone:3: unknown RR type '3600'
        zone acme8.lcl/IN: loading from master file acme8.lcl.zone failed: unexpected end of input
        zone acme8.lcl/IN: not loaded due to errors.
        _default/acme8.lcl/IN: unexpected end of input
```

And this is the acme8.lcl file

```
        $TTL 86400
        @       IN      SOA     ns1.acme8.lcl.
        root.acme8.lcl. (
                2013042201      ;Serial
                3600    ;Refresh
                1800    ;Retry
                604800  ;Expire
                86400   ;Minimum TTL
        )
        ;
                IN      NS      ns1.acme.lcl.
        ;
        ns1     IN      A       10.20.107.11
        ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it, This:

```
   @       IN      SOA     ns1.acme8.lcl.
    root.acme8.lcl. (
```

Should be this:

```
   @       IN      SOA     ns1.acme8.lcl. root.acme8.lcl. (
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, put the `(` on the first line of the record:

```
$origin acme8.lcl.
$ttl 1h
@       SOA    (
                ns1             ; primary nameserver from which slaves should perform a zone transfer
                root            ; email of admin, with @ changed to .
                2013042201      ; monotonically increasing serial number
                1h              ; refresh timer
                30m             ; retry timer
                1w              ; zone expiry timer
                30m             ; Negative TTL
               )
```

or even better, just put everything on one line:

```
$origin acme8.lcl.
$ttl 1h
@       SOA     ns1 root 2013042201 1h 30m 1w 30m
```

It's good practice to always include an `$origin` statement at the start of a zone file (unless you're intentionally making a generic file that's loaded as multiple zones); this serves as a cross-check between `named.conf` and the zonefile that it's being used for the correct name. You can have multiple `$origin` statements in a zonefile, but they must all be the same as, or subdomains of, the zone name specified in `named.conf`.

You don't need to write the zone name wherever it occurs as the suffix of a name in any record (exception: names inside TXT records can't be abbreviated this way).

The "minimum TTL" field is used to determine how long a NXDOMAIN response should be cached, so it's more appropriately named "negative TTL", and it should not have a value greater than 2 hours.

Timers can be expressed as weeks, days, hours, minutes or seconds with a single-letter suffix, or as a combination like `2h30m`